# Highcharts sparklines from ajax-inserted data

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

You have a html table and you want to show sparkline charts from your data, exactly as in this example (from highcharts demos):

https://codepen.io/_dario/pen/rNBOGVR

Highcharts suggested code follows:

```
/**
 * Create a constructor for sparklines that takes some sensible defaults and merges in the individual
 * chart options. This function is also available from the jQuery plugin as $(element).highcharts('SparkLine').
 */
Highcharts.SparkLine = function(a, b, c) {
  var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
    options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
    defaultOptions = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        type: 'area',
        margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
        width: 120,
        height: 20,
        style: {
          overflow: 'visible'
        },

        // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
        skipClone: true
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      xAxis: {
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPositions: []
      },
      yAxis: {
        endOnTick: false,
        startOnTick: false,
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        tickPositions: [0]
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        hideDelay: 0,
        outside: true,
        shared: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          animation: false,
          lineWidth: 1,
          shadow: false,
          states: {
            hover: {
              lineWidth: 1
            }
          },
          marker: {
            radius: 1,
            states: {
              hover: {
                radius: 2
              }
            }
          },
          fillOpacity: 0.25
        },
        column: {
          negativeColor: '#910000',
          borderColor: 'silver'
        }
      }
    };

  options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

  return hasRenderToArg ?
    new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
    new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
};

var start = +new Date(),
  $tds = $('td[data-sparkline]'),
  fullLen = $tds.length,
  n = 0;

// Creating 153 sparkline charts is quite fast in modern browsers, but IE8 and mobile
// can take some seconds, so we split the input into chunks and apply them in timeouts
// in order avoid locking up the browser process and allow interaction.
function doChunk() {
  var time = +new Date(),
    i,
    len = $tds.length,
    $td,
    stringdata,
    arr,
    data,
    chart;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    $td = $($tds[i]);
    stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
    arr = stringdata.split('; ');
    data = $.map(arr[0].split(', '), parseFloat);
    chart = {};

    if (arr[1]) {
      chart.type = arr[1];
    }
    $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
      series: [{
        data: data,
        pointStart: 1
      }],
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
      },
      chart: chart
    });

    n += 1;

    // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
    if (new Date() - time > 500) {
      $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
      setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
      break;
    }

    // Print a feedback on the performance
    if (n === fullLen) {
      $('#result').html('Generated ' + fullLen + ' sparklines in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms');
    }
  }
}
doChunk();
```

However, in my use case, the data in the table (and the *data-sparkline* attribute) are not hard-coded like in the example, but loaded and displayed via an AJAX call, similar to below.

```
//here a table row gets compiled
var tableRow = '<tr id="row_' + word.id + '">';

//this is where the sparkline data go
tableRow += '<td class="has-sparkline"></td></tr>';

//the row gets appended to tbody
$('#wordstable tbody').append(tableRow);

//finally the sparkline data are attached
//data are a simple string such as "1,2,3,4,5"

var rowId = '#row_'+word.id;
var rowIdTd = rowId + ' td.has-sparkline';
$(rowIdTd).data('sparkline',word.sparkline);
```

This breaks the example logic and I can't have Highcharts "see" the data.

No particular error is returned (as the data, as far as Highcharts is concerned, just isn't there, so there's nothing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doChunk` bit just does all the processing in advance, and when you add your row it is no longer processing. One way of dealing with this is pulling out the part that creates a single chart into a separate function (`makeChart`) and when you are doing your processing you use that part directly to create your sparkline.

For example, `doChunk` with split out `makeChart`:

```
function makeChart(td) {
    $td = td;
    stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
    arr = stringdata.split('; ');
    data = $.map(arr[0].split(', '), parseFloat);
    chart = {};

    if (arr[1]) {
      chart.type = arr[1];
    }
    $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
      series: [{
        data: data,
        pointStart: 1
      }],
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
      },
      chart: chart
    });

}

// Creating 153 sparkline charts is quite fast in modern browsers, but IE8 and mobile
// can take some seconds, so we split the input into chunks and apply them in timeouts
// in order avoid locking up the browser process and allow interaction.
function doChunk() {
  var time = +new Date(),
    i,
    len = $tds.length,
    $td,
    stringdata,
    arr,
    data,
    chart;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    makeChart($($tds[i]));

    n += 1;

    // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
    if (new Date() - time > 500) {
      $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
      setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
      break;
    }

    // Print a feedback on the performance
    if (n === fullLen) {
      $('#result').html('Generated ' + fullLen + ' sparklines in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms');
    }
  }
}
```

And then a basic example of your ajax-code:

```
function ajaxIsh() {
    var word = {
    name: 'Bird', // is the word
    id: 'bird',
    sparkline: '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
  };

  //here a table row gets compiled
  var tableRow = '<tr id="row_' + word.id + '">';

  //this is where the sparkline data go
  tableRow += '<th>'+word.name+'</th><td class="has-sparkline"></td></tr>';

  //the row gets appended to tbody
  $('#table-sparkline tbody').append(tableRow);

  //finally the sparkline data are attached
  //data are a simple string such as "1,2,3,4,5"

  var rowId = '#row_'+word.id;
  var rowIdTd = rowId + ' td.has-sparkline';
  $(rowIdTd).data('sparkline',word.sparkline);

  makeChart($(rowIdTd));
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/rv28m3ud/) of it in action.

Comment: yes, I suspected it had to do with that - given that there are not 150+ charts to draw as in the published demo I dispensed with the `doChunk` bit entirely and was able to simplify everything else.